# Appropriate Image size

Tags: android, image-processing

I am making an Android app. Which will be using images which will cover the width of the screen. And the width/height ratio should be 16:9. The images would be loaded over the internet. What should be the size of the image stored on the server so that it has to be suitable for smallest devices to the largest devices. I don't want to keep very large size because that could reduce the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep image according to this screen and it will work on all screen sizes.

```
Normal xhdpi - 640×960 (1280×1920 in design)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the solution in the below link.
[enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

here you can find out the method

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

return inSampleSize;}
```

You can directly use like this

```
mImageView.setImageBitmap(
decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, 100, 100));
```